# Should lop-g, deep-space-gateway and gateway be synonymized? If so, to what?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tagging

We have

- [lop-g](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lop-g) with **5** questions
- [deep-space-gateway](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-space-gateway) with **18** questions
- [gateway](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gateway) with **2** questions

Which may all want to refer to the [Lunar Gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Gateway):

> **The Lunar Gateway, or simply Gateway**, is a planned small space station in lunar orbit intended to serve as a solar-powered communication hub, science laboratory, short-term habitation module, and holding area for rovers and other robots.
>
> **Formerly known as the Deep Space Gateway (DSG)**, the station **was renamed Lunar Orbital Platform-Gateway (LOP-G) in NASA's 2018 proposal** for the 2019 United States federal budget. When the budgeting process was complete[when?], US$332 million had been committed by Congress to preliminary studies.
>
> [...] **The project is expected to play a major role in NASA's Artemis program,** after 2024. While the project is led by NASA, the Gateway is meant to be developed, serviced, and utilized in collaboration with the CSA, ESA, JAXA, and commercial partners. It will serve as the staging point for both robotic and crewed exploration of the lunar south pole, and is the proposed staging point for NASA's Deep Space Transport concept for transport to Mars.

**Question:** Can and should these tags all be synonymized to one? If so, to what?

Comment: Could somebody please also add tag descriptions to these, too?

Comment: @DrSheldon I think the idea is that there will only be one tag; so there's no need for descriptions on each one as most will soon disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose merging and synonymizing [lop-g](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lop-g) and [deep-space-gateway](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deep-space-gateway) into [lunar-gateway](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lunar-gateway), and merging (but not synonymizing) [gateway](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gateway) into [lunar-gateway](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lunar-gateway).

Comment: I'll go for that. Is "merging (but not synonymizing) `gateway` into `lunar-gateway`" simply because it would be redundant; typing gateway will already suggest lunar-gateway without synonymizing them, or is there some more subtle reason? (I'm just curious; I still don't understand how tags work, trying to chip away at it bit-by-bit)

Comment: @uhoh My reason for not synonymizing is because "gateway" is not specific enough. It could easily be used to refer to something else in the future.

Comment: @uhoh The merges are complete. [tag:lunar-gateway] needs a tag excerpt.